# org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: There was an error in the forked process

Tags: java, maven, junit, parallel-processing, cucumber-jvm

I am trying to `.feature` files in parallel but it is giving below error.

I am using:

1. cucumber jvm parallel plugin
2. maven-failsafe-plugin
3. cucumber serenity

**Error:**

```
 Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:3.0.0-M3:verify (default) on project riverbed-automation-tests: There are test failures.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Please refer to F:\workspace\Cuke_Demo\target\failsafe-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
[ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Clock
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:657)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:283)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:246)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1161)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1002)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:848)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:956)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:192)
[ERROR]         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR]         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[ERROR]         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR]         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
```

**POM.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.demo.automation</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo-automation-tests</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Demo Serenity project using Cucumber and WebDriver</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <serenity.version>2.0.40</serenity.version>
        <serenity.cucumber.version>1.9.31</serenity.cucumber.version>
        <webdriver.driver>firefox</webdriver.driver>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>bintray</name>
            <url>http://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>bintray-plugins</name>
            <url>http://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.thucydides</groupId>
            <artifactId>thucydides-junit</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.275</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20090211</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.minidev</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-smart</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-core</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-cucumber</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.temyers/cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.temyers</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-surefire-plugin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>default</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.8</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>run</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <target name="env_setup">
                                        <delete>
                                            <fileset dir="${project.build.outputDirectory}"
                                                includes="*.json" />
                                        </delete>
                                        <copy file="src/main/resources/qa.json"
                                            tofile="${project.build.outputDirectory}/env.json" />
                                    </target>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>qa</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.8</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>run</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <target name="env_setup">
                                        <!-- <task> -->
                                        <delete>
                                            <fileset dir="${project.build.outputDirectory}"
                                                includes="*.json" />
                                        </delete>
                                        <copy file="src/main/resources/qa.json"
                                            tofile="${project.build.outputDirectory}/env.json" />
                                        <!-- </task> -->
                                    </target>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <webdriver.base.url>${webdriver.base.url}</webdriver.base.url>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                    <parallel>classes</parallel>
                    <threadCount>4</threadCount>
                    <perCoreThreadCount>true</perCoreThreadCount>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*.java</include>
                    </includes>
                    <argLine>-Xmx512m</argLine>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <webdriver.driver>${webdriver.driver}</webdriver.driver>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>serenity-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${serenity.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>serenity-reports</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>aggregate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.temyers</groupId>
                <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generateRunners</id>
                        <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generateRunners</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- Mandatory -->
                            <!-- List of package names to scan for glue code. -->
                            <glue>
                                <package>planner.cucumber</package>
                            </glue>
                            <parallelScheme>FEATURE</parallelScheme>
                            <customVmTemplate>src/test/resources/cucumber-serenity-runner.vm</customVmTemplate>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**target/test-classes**
However it is creating files in target folder, see below image.
[image]

Please see what am I missing. Blog I followed was https://johnfergusonsmart.com/running-parallel-tests-serenity-bdd-cucumber/

Comment: The issue `There are test failures...`

Comment: There can't be, I am only doing `syso("Hello World");`